# what difference it makes when coding PHP on windows and linux

Tags: php, linux

I worked/working in core Java, PHP and have strong intention to learn Python and A.I. related languages. But always I do coding (PHP, Java) on windows platform (I feel pity about it myself..) . Always I wanna work in Linux environment. But I wonder what difference it makes. Someone explain me that please. And please provide some good books for linux learning.  I checked google for it. But there comes books in different varieties of it (Administration, Linux programming etc.,).  So to just do coding in PHP on linux platform what level of book I should read for linux.

Note: I am zero in Linux knowledge and I am interested in Linux programming too.

Comment: other than the carriage return difference you should be ok. Go get ubuntu and start learning!

Comment: I suggest you to delete this question, and only difference is Directory Separator.

Comment: @senad: well there are some php functions that dont work in a windows environment (strptime for example)

Comment: Windows is case-insensitive but linux is not. so u have to take care about your directory path and file names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best recommendation is to create a mini project for yourself and dive in.  It won't be easy by any means, but the hands on experience will help you learn.  Maybe, take one of your existing PHP or Java applications and attempt to get it working in Linux.  As a starting point, you'll need LAMP for PHP, and Tomcat for your java applications if they're web based.  You might want to start first with a very user friendly OS such as Ubuntu.  Then move on to RHEL (CentOS is free).

The biggest differences that I've found are the communities and the cost.  The cost difference is a common debate between people in businesses concerning achieving business needs with open source or proprietary solutions.  When I mention the communities, in my experience, I've always found that open source projects tend to have more robust communities that feel, in my words, "real".  Some of the proprietary communities feel like their driven by $$$ and marketing.  However, that is just my opinion.

On a side note, since expanding Linux knowledge on my resume, I have had a lot more job opportunities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly... I've a planned a website to build ... decided to do it using LAMP stack.

Answer (score 4):

I can see two questions from your text:

1) Does PHP programming on Linux differ from PHP programming on Windows?

Answer: No, it does not. There may be other tools that you work with, but even on Windows you have plenty of choices (from a simple Notepad to an IDE). Lots of tools (e.g. IDEs like NetBeans or Eclipse) are available on both platforms, which makes the switch to Linux even easier. 
If you want to run the Script on your local machine, you could install a basic LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL PHP) configuration on your system, comparable to e.g. XAMPP on Windows. Or you could install just the php-cli (command line interface), without the complete webserver, if you want to run only some scripts in command line.

2) Is Linux difficult to use?

Answer: No, it is not :-) The best way to find it out is to get e.g. the very user-friendly Linux Distribution [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) and try it on your own. You can run the System as a Live CD without installing anything, if you want to test things.
After working a bit with Linux, you get quickly used to it and even developing applications shouldn't be that hard.

I can't recommend any books, though. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 0):

To learn linux you must learn shell scripting. Without shell scripting linux is nothing. I think this is the mean reason that the programmers select linux for their coding. I recommend you take a look on this [site](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/).Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I started programming in Linux just two weeks back, before that i was always programming in Windows.

Theres no difference, except if you use any Specific IDE, i use PHP Storm and that was available in linux as well so its almost the same.

Also you will need to get used to with some Shell commands to get used to it, but without starting you wont learn anything. just install a ubuntu along with windows and you will get fluent very soon. now i hardly open windows :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last part of your question:

> So to just do coding in PHP on linux platform what level of book I should read?

You can read any beginning PHP book. Whether you are writing your code on a Windows or Linux OS, the end result is the same, a .php file. When you load a page in your browser, the PHP file gets interpreted and compiled by the PHP server. The file that it produces then gets rendered by your browser. So whether you are running firefox on windows, or linux, it really doesnt matter. I hope this clears up some of your confusion.

If you are a beginner, I would suggest you do some experimenting on a server that is already set-up for you, as configuring and installing one on Linux can be confusing at first. Try some simple scripts etc etc, and pick up a book on beginning linux.